# Swift: How to smoothly move GMSMarker between 2 coordinaets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

I have added a route and i have also added the way point markers. i want to move the marker smoothly from one gps coordinate point to another smoothly along the route. can anyone help me with this? here is the code that is used to add markers.

```
func configureMapAndMarkersForRoute() {
  viewGMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(mapTasks.originCoordinate, zoom: 9.0)

  originMarker = GMSMarker(position: self.mapTasks.originCoordinate)
  originMarker.map = self.viewGMap
  originMarker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImageWithColor(UIColor.greenColor())
  originMarker.title = self.mapTasks.originAddress

  destinationMarker = GMSMarker(position: self.mapTasks.destinationCoordinate)
  destinationMarker.map = self.viewGMap
  destinationMarker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImageWithColor(UIColor.redColor())
  destinationMarker.title = self.mapTasks.destinationAddress

  if waypointsArray.count > 0 {
    var i = 0
    for waypoint in waypointsArray {
      let lat: Double = (waypoint.componentsSeparatedByString(",")[0] as NSString).doubleValue
      let lng: Double = (waypoint.componentsSeparatedByString(",")[1] as NSString).doubleValue

      let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng))
      marker.map = viewGMap
      marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImageWithColor(UIColor.purpleColor())
      marker.title = locationNameArray[i]
      markersArray.append(marker)
      i += 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding marker every time ? just move single marker along path ...

Comment: @kishan94 yes. that's what i want to do. can you help me with this?

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if you found the my solution correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check below code ...

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:5.0];
CGPoint point = [mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:destCoordinate];
//    point.x = point.x + 100;
GMSCameraUpdate *camera =
[GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:[mapView.projection coordinateForPoint:point]];
[mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:camera];
markerToMove.position = destCoordinate;
[CATransaction commit];
```

loop through all points you getting for path ..and set next destCoordinate as each next point ....

Answer (score 6):

Swift:

```
func updateMarker(coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D, degrees: CLLocationDegrees, duration: Double) {
    // Keep Rotation Short
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
    marker.rotation = degrees
    CATransaction.commit()

    // Movement
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(duration)
    marker.position = coordinates

    // Center Map View
    let camera = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(coordinates)
    mapView.animateWithCameraUpdate(camera)

    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Comment: I have small doubt. I want rotation of marker based on latitude & longitude from server

Comment: @sahil kapoor...I am facing one problem...if distance is high between two points how do you handle animation in that case?

Comment: You can increase the duration accordingly or calculate based on the distance between coordinates to optimize speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var driverPositionMarker: GMSMarker?

func displayDriverPosition(on mapView: GMSMapView, with coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        if let marker = driverPositionMarker {
            let heading = GMSGeometryHeading(marker.position, coordinate)
            marker.rotation = heading
            marker.position = coordinate
        } else {
            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = coordinate
            marker.iconView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "CarMarker"))
            marker.map = mapView
            driverPositionMarker = marker
        }
}
```